# Получить несмещенный объект Date из строки

Tags: javascript, дата

Я пытаюсь получить объект Date из строки

```
const str = 2020-11-19T05:00:00.000Z
console.log(new Date(str));
```

Но когда я так делаю, то время преобразуется к времени у меня на компьютере (у меня московское время):

```
Thu Nov 19 2020 08:00:00 GMT+0300 (Москва, стандартное время)
```

Как сделать так, чтобы я получал Date без преобразования времени к локальному?

Comment: на самом деле ничего не преобразуется. Просто ты неправильно проверяешь значение. Тем более 8 часов по Москве, это по 5 часов по UTC - все верно.

Comment: @Grundy возможно я неясно выразился, уточню: я хочу получить время по UTC, а не по Москве

Comment: Время всегда в UTC, просто при выводе он приводится к локальному. Для форматирования вывода можно воспользоваться [`toUTCString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toUTCString) или [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-й вариант:

```
let str = '2020-11-19T05:00:00.000Z'
let d = new Date(str);

var day = d.getUTCDate();
var month = d.getUTCMonth();
var year = d.getUTCFullYear();
var hour = d.getUTCHours();
var minute = d.getUTCMinutes();
var second = d.getUTCSeconds();

console.log(`${day}.${month}.${year} ${hour}:${minute}:${second}`)

//19.10.2020 5:0:0
```

2-й вариант:

```
let str = '2020-11-19T05:00:00.000Z'
let date = new Date(str);

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString('ru-RU'));
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString('ru-RU',{hour12: false, timeZone: "UTC"}));

//19.11.2020
//05:00:00
```